# Declare a functional component as "pure"

Tags: reactjs

How to signal to React that a functional component is "pure", as an equivalent of `React.PureComponent` for component classes?

```
function C(props) { 
  return <var>{props.n}</var> 
}
```

**without** making it a class

```
class C extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
     return <var>{this.props.n}</var>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

As of React 16.6.0, [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) has been added, so the answer is now:

```js
const C = React.memo(props => {
  return <var>{props.n}</var>
})
```

Comment: Should we add this to all pure components?
Or if we follow a container view pattern should we add memo to all views?

Comment: @coder Naively, yes, but in practice, I'm not so sure. It does have a performance cost: diffing props, and of course a performance benefit: avoiding re-renders when the props didn't change. Your best bet is to benchmark the app with and without.

Answer (score 16):

Based on the concept of purity in functional programming paradigms, a function is pure if:

- Its return value is only determined by its input values
- Its return value is always the same for the same input values

There seem two ways to do it for React functional components:

1. Using [**`memo`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) from **`react`**:

   ```
   import React, { memo } from 'react';

   const Component = (props) {
     return (
       // Component code
     )
   }

   // Wrap component using "memo" HOC
   export default memo(Component);
   ```
2. Using **`pure`** from [**`recompose`**](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose):

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { pure } from 'recompose';

   const Component = (props) {
     return (
       // Component code
     )
   }

   // Wrap component using "pure" HOC
   export default pure(Component);
   ```

Comment: Could you specify recompose benefits over native react solution?

Answer (score 13):

To @Shubham and @Andrew:
No, functional components are not `PureComponent`s. Functional components will always get re-render if the parent component re-renders. A PureComponent contains a default `shouldComponentUpdate()` and I think that's what OP wants.

---

You can use `pure` provided by [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) to wrap and optimize your functional components:

```
import pure from 'recompose/pure'

const YourFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  ...
}

export default pure(YourFunctionalComponent)
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to CodinCat answer.

The author of the library, [recomponse](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose), wrote [a note](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#a-note-from-the-author-acdlite-oct-25-2018) on 25th Oct of 2018, where he stated, that what he tried to solve by the library was solved by the React Team through introducing hooks. Not only that, React team added optimization feature like [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), which was named as `React.pure()` earlier. So, it's time to use `React.memo()`. Read Official Docs about it