# Assign Nested map unique key, javascrpit

Tags: javascript, array-map

I need to assign assign each input their own id.

```
const sep = words.map((word, ind) => {
  return (
     <div key={ind} className="guess__word">
       {word.split("").map((letter, id) => {
         if (letter === " ") {
           return <SpaceBox key={id} letter={letter} />;
         } else {
           return <LetterBox key={id} id={id} letter={letter} />;
         }
      })}
     </div>
   );
 });
```

The problem that I am having is that due to the map being nested, the  value of id keeps reseting back to 0. Each word of words has a different length so if kinda hard to figure out if there is a math equation that would help me solve this.

for reference, the length of each word is 10, 3, 4, and 4.

Also I need the ids to equal up to the length of words. So I would need the ids to be 0-20.

Comment: What you’re saying doesn’t make logical sense. You need an id per letter per word. But you’re saying you can’t have more ids than words. This is logically not possible.

Comment: Yes to that first part. I think you were misunderstanding me. I was considering the fact that count starts at 0 so it would still techincally add up to 21 ( the length of words (10 + 3 + 4 + 4 =21) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if kinda hard to figure out if there is a math equation that would help me solve this.

There is - given indicies X and Y, you can map onto the Xth prime number raised to the Y power - but that's way overkill here. Just use string concatenation, for the key, eg indicies 3 and 4 can produce a key of `3_4`.

I'd recommend [not using `.split('')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-to-get-character-array-from-a-string) to get a character array from a string - invoke the array's iterator instead, otherwise you'll occasionally run into problems when odd characters are present.

```
const sep = words.map((word, ind) => {
  return (
     <div key={ind} className="guess__word">
       {[...word].map((letter, id) => {
         const key = `${ind}_${id}`;
         if (letter === " ") {
           return <SpaceBox key={key} letter={letter} />;
         } else {
           return <LetterBox key={key} id={id} letter={letter} />;
         }
      })}
     </div>
   );
 });
```

If the words may change, you might want to use a slightly different key, to differentiate a `SpaceBox` letter from a `LetterBox` letter.

```
<LetterBox key={key + ' '} id={id} letter={letter} />
```

If you have to use only array indicies in order starting from 0, it'll be uglier - declare the last used number outside, and use and increment it inside the loop.

```
let lastId = -1;
const sep = words.map((word) => {
  return (
     <div key={ind} className="guess__word">
       {[...word].map((letter) => {
         if (letter === " ") {
           return <SpaceBox key={++lastId} letter={letter} />;
         } else {
           return <LetterBox key={++lastId} id={lastId} letter={letter} />;
         }
      })}
     </div>
   );
 });
```

Due to the odd key requirement, the above is only a good approach if the words are static. If they may change, [memoize the boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208385) based on the `words`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for super quick response. I updated my question but he had already answered before I could edit it. I need the ids to match the length of the words array(21). Is there a way to do that? I have a work around if not but it would be great if there was.

Answer (score 0):

To save math, you might as well just concatenate the numbers in a meaningful way

```
const sep = words.map((word, ind) => {
  return (
     <div key={ind} className="guess__word">
       {word.split("").map((letter, id) => {
         const key = `${ind}-{key}`;
         if (letter === " ") {
           return <SpaceBox key={key} letter={letter} />;
         } else {
           return <LetterBox key={key} id={id} letter={letter} />;
         }
      })}
     </div>
   );
 });
```